# Make python script double clickable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that subprocess.Popen's another one .
1) How can i make it double clickable on mac? 
I tried so much things like pyinstaller, platypus, and so on...

Here's my code

```py
import subprocess
import pyautogui
import sys
import timeit
import time



def get_var_value(filename="varstore.dat"):
    with open(filename, "a+") as f:
        f.seek(0)
        val = int(f.read() or 0) + 1
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()
        f.write(str(val))
        return val

your_counter = get_var_value()

p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'questions.py'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write(b'N\nG\n0\na\n')
p.stdin.flush()
time.sleep(15)
p.stdin.write(b'\n')
p.stdin.flush()
p.stdin.write(f'GlobalAndroid{your_counter}\n'.encode())
p.stdin.flush()
p.stdin.write(b'omega\n')
```

2) I tried some codes to insert the time the bot has been running, but didnt work. 
What this script does basically is, it opens my "questions.py" script which is a script that asks 4 questions before opening a captcha and after the captcha has been done, it asks 2 more questions before starting to count from 0 to "till i stop it" (dont ask me why hahahah i have my purpose).
What I would want is to add the time it took from the moment it started to count from 0 to the point it stops. 
I tried different things like a variable with time.time() but it gave me the time the bot has been running only till the captcha opens, like you can see here

[image]

How could I do that?

Comment: In Linux (and probably in Mac too) you have to add shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python` in first line and you have to set attribute `executable` -  ie. `chmod +x your_script.py`

Comment: Yeah i tried everythin @furas, check the comments below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a shebang line. This must be the first line of the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

You can use whichever Python interpreter you prefer. You can find a command's path with `where` e.g.

`$ where python`

And then you can use the absolute path in the shebang. This even works for virtualenvs.

You must also set the executable flag. Use `$ chmod +x myscript.py` for whatever script you want executable like that.

If you have the `.py` extension associated with something else already, try changing the file from `.py` to `.command` on macOS.

If you have the standard Python distribution from python.org, you should also have a Python launcher. You could associate that with the `.py` extension instead of IDLE.

You can also try making a [zipapp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html). Then you'd use the `.pyz` extension.

Comment: It still just does open the python idle without running anything

Comment: Still just opens python idle.
But then i tried to change go to "Infos" of the file, and change the program to open with to terminal. Then i succeded to double click but then this problem! 
![Valid XHTML](http://prntscr.com/nt0pdi).

Comment: @Ace Perhaps you ran it with the wrong interpreter? Try `python3` in the shebang.

Comment: @Ace so now double click works but you have problem in Python code. Maybe you run it with Python 3.5 ? f-string needs Python 3.6. Or maybe you have two Pythons installed and you have to use full path to correct Python in shebang. You can also check if you have command `python3.6` or `python3.7`

Comment: @Ace I meant `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, not `#!python3`. There are a lot of places Python could be installed on a mac. You have to find the right one. How do you run it from the command line normally?

Comment: @furas im not sure the problem is python. Check my screenshot, as you can see, im running python3.7, but like you see on the screen, the problem is that now it says that the "questions.py" doesnt exist when actually it does and is in the same directory

Comment: @Ace second screenshot doesn't show if you use 3.7 but it shows problem in line with `f".."` which can be problem in 3.5 or older.

Comment: @Ace on first screenshot it may try to run python and script in different folder and then it may not find it. But I don't know solution for this.